# Container types in Golang

Tags: programming-languages, algorithms, google, go

For a non-OOP language like google Go, is it idiomatic to go about implementing new container types using datatypes like arrays or lists so as to implement convenient functionality like `contains` method which is absent from all in built container types?

Comment: Go is object oriented, just not in the “usual” way (it doesn't use classes, but just structs and methods).

Comment: maps can be checked if they have a specific key: _, ok := m[key]. If the key was present, ok is true. Since Go doesn't let you override operators, "contains" doesn't make sense unless you have a container of builtin types.

Answer (score 2):

The [container](http://golang.org/pkg/container/) package currently contains built-in objects for heaps, doubly linked lists, and circular lists. The source code for the container/list package also gives the idiomatic way to iterate over lists. With datatypes so easy to define, I don't think there is any problem in implementing new containers on your own. I would also imagine that as Go matures, it will add additional built-in data structures.

A channel is essentially a FIFO queue; see this [source](https://sites.google.com/site/gopatterns/concurrency/semaphores) for help on making your own types thread-safe.